# como capturar el valor de un swal y mandarla a data con ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, base-de-datos

buenas tardes tengo una duda por desconocimiento acabo de crear un alert mediante un swal el cual tiene un campo de texto ... necesito que cuando escriba en ese campo y le de a guardar me capture la informacion y me la inserte en la base de dato...

la cuestion es que normalmente en un campo de texto tenemos la etiqueta id con su valor .. ejemplo **id="valor"** ... ahora con el swall no pasa eso ... no se si lo tengo ya o no en el cod me podrian audar ?

```
Swal.fire({
               
              title: 'informacion',
              input: 'text',
              inputLabel: "¿Desea rechazar peticion del cliente ?  Escriba el motivo :",
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: 'Guardar',
              allowOutsideClick: false,
              inputValidator: (value) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve) => {
                        if (value) {
            var valor_recibido = value
            resolve()

            console.log(valor_recibido)

        } else {
            resolve('Por favor escriba el Motivo')
        }
    })
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

En la guia de **SweetAlert** tienes un ejemplo practico, el mismo se realiza con `fetch` para consumir una `API`.

```js
swal({
  text: 'Search for a movie. e.g. "La La Land".',
  content: "input",
  button: {
    text: "Search!",
    closeModal: false,
  },
})
.then(name => {
  if (!name) throw null;
 
  return fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=${name}&entity=movie`);
})
.then(results => {
  return results.json();
})
.then(json => {
  const movie = json.results[0];
 
  if (!movie) {
    return swal("No movie was found!");
  }
 
  const name = movie.trackName;
  const imageURL = movie.artworkUrl100;
 
  swal({
    title: "Top result:",
    text: name,
    icon: imageURL,
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  if (err) {
    swal("Oh noes!", "The AJAX request failed!", "error");
  } else {
    swal.stopLoading();
    swal.close();
  }
});
```

En tu caso tienes que especificar la ruta a donde se enviara el dato y el metodo que seria `POST`.

Puedes revisar este ejemplo haciendo click [aqui](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#ajax-requests) y como usar `fetch` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) .